# How to search for comments containing keyword in all Reddit using praw or similar?

Tags: python, api, reddit, praw

If I want to search on Reddit for comments containing a keyword, the website has an URL like this:

```
https://www.reddit.com/search/?q=exampletest&include_over_18=1&type=comment
```

and the search is very fast and immediately find results, it's "**native**".

If I try to do that with praw, with for example something like this:

```
reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id=CLIENT_ID, client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET, user_agent=USER_AGENT, username=USERNAME, password=PASSWORD)
my_keywords = ['exampletest']

for comment in reddit.subreddit('all').stream.comments():
    cbody = comment.body
    print(cbody)
    if any(keyword in cbody for keyword in my_keywords):
        print("found")
```

it doesn't find anything because I think it literally search that keyword in all r/all posts. The search is **not** optimized **like** the "**native**" Reddit website search.
Is there a way to do what Reddit website does with its "native" search, but using praw?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed scraping results within the url:
[https://www.reddit.com/search/?q=exampletest&include\_over\_18=1&type=comment](https://www.reddit.com/search/?q=exampletest&include%5C_over%5C_18=1&type=comment)